# How to redirect specific file I/O to another drive

Tags: windows, filesystems, symbolic-link, io, temporary-files

I'm on Windows and i'm dealing with a badly written application that needs to store huge temporary files, but the temp directory is apparently hardcoded to `%localappdata%\Temp` and cannot be changed.

My primary partition, where the `%localappdata%` resides, is however not big enough and cannot store all temporary files the application wants to create.

Is there any way to redirect the file I/O for that application at the OS level, so that the data goes to a different drive where is enough space for it? I tried to create a standard Windows shortcut but that didn't work.

Comment: You *could* simply change your temp directory somewhere else using Junctions or Hard Links? .. No?? Then you wouldn't need modification of the source code or change the the environment.  Speaking of that.. %localappdata% is an environment variable.  You could point it somewhere else when launching the app.. either by simple means or by editing the environment used by `CreateProcess()`

Comment: You might be able to create a app compat shim to do this.  You generate a .sdb file and install it on the computer with sdbinst.exe.  Download the Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit. Create an Application Fix using the 32 or 64-bit tool depending on the target application. You should try the CorrectFilePaths shim.

Comment: Hmm, i was wrong. The application actually uses environment variable `%TEMP%` to store its data into. I was able to modify the application's shortcut according to this https://netlicensing.io/blog/2012/06/15/set-environment-variables-in-windows-shortcut/ so that it sets the TEMP variable prior to launching it.

Comment: @Youda008 if you have a solution it would be good to post an answer saying what you did and how it works. You should be able to accept your answer after a day or so and close the loop on your question. This is the kind of thing that can help people in the future and other people might be able to post different solutions.

Comment: @Mokubai Well i solved my specific case, but i don't have answer to my question because the question is little bit more general. I did not manage to redirect writing to arbitrary file/folder, i just managed to redirect writing to a system Temp folder, which happened to be enough for that application.

Comment: @Youda008 which is still a solution and should be posted as it can help other users who have a similar problem in the future. If you said how you found out that it was using an environment variable that you could simply reassign then other users might find it incredibly useful.